# Why JSON to Array requires double JSON.parse?

Tags: arrays, json

I'm creating widget that adds filters to my page. I keep info about added filters in local storage, but the magic happens when i try to decode JSON. It requires double json parse to become array object again.

Here is the code: (this.filters is an array like this: `["filter_id", "filter_id2"]` etc.)

```
getFilters: function() {
    var json_str = localStorage.getItem("debt_filters");
    // BUG with quoting: json => array requires double parse :/
    this.filters = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(json_str))) || [];
},
setFilter: function() {
    var json_str = this.createFilterJson();
    localStorage.setItem("debt_filters", json_str);
},
createFilterJson: function() {
    return encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.filters));
},
```

Comment: Can you add a sample value for `json_str`?

Comment: `debt_filters=%22%5B%5C%22department_name%5C%22%2C%20%5C%22user%5C%22%2C%20%5C%22department_name_user%5C%22%5D%22` this is the localStorage value (json_str in getFilters), and this is JSON before url encode(for example in createFilterJson) `"[\"department_name\", \"user\", \"department_name_user\", \"buyer\"]"` I have a feeling that this escaping quotes has something to do here.